# Solver foundation, strange behaviour

Tags: c#, optimization, solver, ms-solver-foundation

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var context= SolverContext.GetContext();
            var model = context.CreateModel();

            var index = new Set(Domain.IntegerRange(0, 6), "index");

            var x = new Decision(Domain.IntegerRange(0, 5), "x", index);
            model.AddDecision(x);

            // When I uncomment the following line, values ends
            // up with only 3 elements instead of 7 as expected

            // model.AddConstraint("constraint", x[0] + x[1] + x[2] == 2);

            model.AddGoal("objective", GoalKind.Minimize, Model.Sum(Model.ForEach(index, i => Model.Power(x[i] - 2, 2))));

            context.Solve();
            var values = x.GetValues().ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this code as it is, Solver Foundation correctly calculates seven values each equal to 2.

When I uncomment `model.AddConstraint("constraint", x[0] + x[1] + x[2] == 2)`, at the end values only contains three values: 0, 1 and 1. Why doesn't it contain the remaining values?

What's going on?

Comment: did you try to solve the same model with OML and command-line utility?

Comment: No I didn't. TBH I don't know how to use those tools and I don't want to invest the time learning them, when the above code should work. Thanks anyway for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your sample with active constraint, it comes up with `0+1+1` as solution and omits `x[3] .. x[6]`. This looks like a bug. All of them should have value `2`.

Add the following lines to display the results:

```
foreach (object[] value in values)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("x[{0}] = {1}", value[1], value[0]);
   }
```

Perhaps, the blog of [Nathan Brixius](http://nathanbrixius.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/getting-solution-values-using-solver-foundation-services/) might provide some insights.

After adding the following dummy constraint, I've got the full set of variables again:

```
    model.AddConstraint("constraint2", (x[3] + x[4] + x[5] + x[6]) < 999);
```

---

As an **alternative**, you could turn to [MiniZinc](http://www.minizinc.org/) and use a simple model like this:

```
set of int: ix = 0..6;
array[ix] of var 0..5: x;

constraint
    x[0] + x[1] + x[2] == 2;

solve minimize sum(i in ix)((x[i] - 2)*(x[i] - 2));

output 
["\nx[" ++ show(i) ++ "] = " ++ show(x[i]) | i in ix] ;
```